# bootstrap columns won't create spaces between them no matter what I try, is it my html structure?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns, rows

I have searched through almost every question asked about spacing between bootstrap columns but nothing seems to work. I'm thinking it could be a simple rookie mistake with the way I have structured my html/css but I can't seem to figure it out.

I've worked with bootstrap many times before but using a theme, this is my first time however only using a simple bootstrap navbar template with nothing else inside.

```css
.img-container{
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}
.img-container .overlay{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
}
.img-container:hover .overlay{
   display: block;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.img-container .overlay .services-caption{
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 25%;
   left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<!--Services-->
<section class="services">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">     
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="images/services/shop.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="overlay">
            <span class="services-caption">Shop</span>       
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-md-4">     
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="images/services/shop.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="overlay">
            <span class="services-caption">Shop</span>
          </div>
        </div>     
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">     
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="images/services/shop.jpg" alt="..."> 
          <div class="overlay">
            <span class="services-caption">Shop</span>
          </div>
        </div>     
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: .img-container{
 position: relative;display: inline-block;padding-left:10px;
}

Comment: Why don't you try add padding to img-container class? If you want spaces then you have to add padding to your image container, zero padding and 100% width means it will start from the leftmost corner and spread out to the rightmost corner.

Comment: what ends up happening is that all of the columns shift to the right and the overlay gets left behind. Also, there isn't any visible space created between the columns.

Comment: I'm guessing its the way I have structured my html in order to do the overlay effect but not sure.

Comment: There is space if you contain the image within the parent element. All I did was add some images here and add `max-width: 100%` to the img tags. Without a proper working demo of your issue, it's hard to give you real advice. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpjoYe

Comment: That won't be necessary Michael! I've looked at your code and set my images to 100% max-width and it worked like magic!!! Wish I could give you an aswered response or a thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

Add bootstrap `col-md-offset-*` class to achieve spacing between columns.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
```

The above code will create a gap of 1 column size.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion neophyte, but I've already tried that method. What ends up happening is that it will give too much spacing and causes the columns to proceed to the next row.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `padding`, put test class on each `<div class="col-md-4 test">`

```
<style>
    .test {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>
<div class="col-md-4 test">
    <div class="img-container">

        <img src="images/services/shop.jpg" alt="...">

        <div class="overlay">
            <span class="services-caption">Shop</span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class called img-responsive. It will make the image responsively.

```
  <div class="col-md-4">                    
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="images/services/shop.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
      <div class="overlay">
        <span class="services-caption">Shop</span>                          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```